# Regarding an entire function being affine

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-algebras, entire-functions

I have been reading this article [A characterization of multiplicative linear functionals in Banach algebras](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm67/sm67113.pdf) and got stuck in the middle of the proof of theorem 1.2 on page 217.
In the 3rd line from below, they say that the function $f_{a,b}:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is Lipschitz and entire *hence it is affine*. Can anyone tell me why it would be affine. Or suggest me a reference to the result which states that an Lipschitz entire complex function will be affine.

Or can you tell other conditions for an entire function to be affine?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101221090813AA6d8dG

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_{a,b}$ is Lipschitz, its derivative is bounded.  A bounded entire constant is constant, so $f_{a,b}$ is an antiderivative of a constant, so it is affine.

Comment: "Lipschitz and entire" is in the question @ClementC.